# Javascript Execution in optional Block Jelly

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

Is there any way to execute **Javascript** in an **optional block** of Jelly?

**Use Case:** I want to update another section on the page each time there is a toggle on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute javascript in Jelly script, you need to call javascript from `<script>` tag, e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert("Hello World!");
```

you need to fetch id of the section and refresh it on js event or simply use jelly core tags `<j:core>` with html basic input tags

For refreshing option block or any other section you may need to do something,

```
<f:checkbox name="${attrs.name}" class="optional-block-control block-control" onclick="javascript:updateOptionalBlock(this,true)"
                  negative="${attrs.negative}" checked="${attrs.checked}" field="${attrs.field}" title="${title}" /
```

Also for advanced execution, you can check `<j:choose>`, `<j:when>` like tags and bind that with your backend code and refresh dynamically.

It is better to check some advance GitHub code :)
[https://github.com/jenkinsci...](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/lib/form/optionalBlock.jelly)